# How to hit the WebSocket Endpoint?

Tags: javascript, curl, websocket

I see that there is websocket endpoint which works out fins with Java tests. In logs I see

```
Connecting to: ws://127.0.0.1:8080/76f48a44-0af8-444c-ba97-3f1ed34afc91/tweets
```

Just like any other `REST` API I would like to hit it via browser or curl, but when I do that I see

```
➜  tweetstream git:(master) ✗ curl ws://127.0.0.1:8080/b9b90525-4cd4-43de-b893-7ef107ad06c2/tweets  
curl: (1) Protocol ws not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

and

```
➜  tweetstream git:(master) ✗ curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/b9b90525-4cd4-43de-b893-7ef107ad06c2/tweets
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Not Found</body></html>%
```

Is there a way to test websocket APIs with browser/curl?

Comment: Websockets is not a RESTful protocol like HTTP is. Make sure you use the right tool for the job.

Comment: Do you know the right tools? I am pretty new with websockets

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you mean literally to test the implementation of websockets, I found Autobahn's test suite to be very useful:  http://autobahn.ws/

If you just want to noodle with a websocket I would recommend using the developer tools in a browser like chrome to make a connection and send/recv data:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/76f48a44-0af8-444c-ba97-3f1ed34afc91/tweets");
ws.onclose = function() { // thing to do on close
};
ws.onerror = function() { // thing to do on error
};
ws.onmessage = function() { // thing to do on message
};
ws.onopen = function() { // thing to do on open
};
ws.send("Hello World");
```

Answer (score 16):

This did the trick for me:

```
$ curl -i -N -H "Connection: Upgrade" -H "Upgrade: websocket" -H "Host: echo.websocket.org" -H "Origin: http://www.websocket.org" http://echo.websocket.org
```

from: http://www.thenerdary.net/post/24889968081/debugging-websockets-with-curl

Comment: there is no endpoint, it's only testing the root url. I think the original question is about specific endpoints such as ip:port/endpoint/

Answer (score 9):

For completeness, I'd like to add my own CLI tool: [websocat](https://github.com/vi/websocat).

```
$ websocat wss://echo.websocket.org/
qwer
qwer
1234
1234
```

It does not do the "browser" part of the question, but should be a valid substitute for "curl" in this case.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see that, I saw this https://github.com/vi/websocat/issues/1 todo list and found "Specifying cookies and other HTTP headers." at the end, and didn't notice that the box beside it was checked, And didn't notice that it was from 2018. Sorry, I should have been more sure before commenting. I'll remove the comment now and this comment in a bit of time so you see it.

Answer (score 5):

I had to use this command to make it work:

```
$ curl -i -N -H "Connection: Upgrade" -H "Upgrade: websocket" -H "Host: echo.websocket.org" -H "Origin: http://www.websocket.org" -H "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" -H 'Sec-WebSocket-Key: +onQ3ZxjWlkNa0na6ydhNg==' http://www.websocket.org
```

I am using Jetty, and if I didn't add the Sec-WebSocket-Version/Sec-WebSocket-Key doesn't work. Just for the record.

Answer (score 2):

I have used this and found it to be quite simple

http://www.websocket.org/echo.html

Answer (score 1):

```
curl --include \
--no-buffer \
--header "Connection: Upgrade" \
--header "Upgrade: websocket" \
--header "Host: echo.websocket.org" \
--header "Origin: http://echo.websocket.org" \
--header "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" \
http://echo.websocket.org
```

Add the header if you have an additional sub-protocol configured for the WebSocket endpoint:

```
--header "Sec-protocol: protocol-name"
```

Replace thee Origin, Host and endpoint to test with your own server. If you have basic auth enabled, add the Authorization header like this:

```
 --header "Authorization: Basic RVZCLVAxNzI2MzAzOv"
```

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** `` curl -H 'Upgrade: websocket' -H "Sec-WebSocket-Key: `openssl rand -base64 16`" -H 'Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13' --http1.1 -sSv https://ws.ifelse.io `` (depending on the server you might need to provide `Origin` and/or `Connection: Upgrade`)

First, how does the websocket protocol work in a few words? A client connects to a server, sends a handshake request, receives "101 Switching Protocols" (a handshake response) after which they send [frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Base_Framing_Protocol) back and forth.

The handshake looks along the following lines:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ws.example.com
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: x3JJHMbDL1EzLkh9GBhXDw==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: http://example.com

HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: HSmrc0sMlYUkAGmm5OPpG2HaGWk=
```

[`Upgrade`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Upgrade) makes it switch from HTTP(s) to the websocket protocol.

[`Connection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection) specifies that `Upgrade` is a [hop-by-hop](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9110#field.connection) header (headers that intermediaries should consume, not forward). But my experiments show that it works w/o this header. Or to be more precise, it might be optional if there's a reverse proxy in front of the server (e.g. `nginx`).

[`Sec-WebSocket-Key`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-11.3.1)/[`Sec-WebSocket-Accept`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-11.3.3) is a security measure described [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-11.3.1), [here](https://trac.ietf.org/trac/hybi/wiki/FAQ#WhatSec-WebSocket-KeyandSec-WebSocket-Acceptarefor) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Protocol_handshake).

[`Sec-WebSocket-Version`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-11.3.5) specifies the websocket protocol version. According to RFC 6455 it [should be equal](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#page-18) 13.

[`Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) is needed when the client is a browser and the origin of the requesting page doesn't match the origin of the websocket server URL.

A detailed description of what should constitute a websocket handshake request can be found [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#page-17).

That's how it goes with HTTP/1.1. HTTP/2 is a [different story](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8441).

Knowing this to establish a websocket connection with `curl`:

```
$ curl -H 'Upgrade: websocket' \
       -H "Sec-WebSocket-Key: `openssl rand -base64 16`" \
       -H 'Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13' \
       --http1.1 \
       -sSv \
       https://ws.ifelse.io
...
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: ws.ifelse.io
> Upgrade: websocket
> Sec-WebSocket-Key: e2dujvcbYbN747lapeH+WA==
> Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
...
< HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
< Connection: upgrade
< upgrade: websocket
< sec-websocket-accept: 6wmMGMtN00aWw3loYd6P36EHKMI=
```

The other options are [`wscat`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wscat), [`websocat`](https://github.com/vi/websocat).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a cURL like WebSocket client. You can send single data frame (text/binary) via this tool and then it closes the socket. Also you can add HTTP headers in the initial HTTP upgrade process.

https://github.com/jussmen/WebSocket_cURL

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13281443)

Comment: @CastroRoy, hmm, appears as a legitimate answer although I didn't test it working.

Comment: Anyone just finding this, the application does not work or no longer works, tested with python2 and python3.