# Linux Bash: How to open a websocket connection as client

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, curl, websocket

I have created a Node.JS application that provides a web socket server (using [npm ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws)). This websocket waits until a connection is established. Once a connection hits the server, the websocket executes a job. When the job is done, a message is sent over the socket, then the socket is being closed. 
This socket works as expected; already tested it with another Node.JS script.

How can I **connect to the web socket** using only linux **command line** tools? 
I already tried curl as described [here](http://www.thenerdary.net/post/24889968081/debugging-websockets-with-curl). However, I can not find out how to connect properly to my websocket which runs at localhost:8088/socket/

**Edit:**
My question has been identified as a possible duplicate of [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24704097/how-to-hit-the-websocket-endpoint) question. However, the linked question only asks if there is a way to do it with curl. I'd be glad to see any solution which works on bash. Also, the answer to the linked question is a javascript file using autobahn.ws

Answer (score 45, accepted):

My tool [websocat](https://github.com/vi/websocat) is specifically designed for this.

```
websocat ws://your_server/url
```

You can connect and exchange data with your server. By default each line becomes a WebSocket text message and vice versa.

On Linux it is more comfortable to play with it using readline:

```
rlwrap websocat ws://your_server/url.
```

It is not the only CLI websocket client. There are also "ws" and "wscat" projects.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the tool. Is it possible to install it permissionless ? At the office we do not have sudo access

Comment: @GeorgiosPligoropoulos Yes, just download appropriate pre-built executable from Github releases and run it. Multiple variants may be runnable. You can also download and extract deb package.

Comment: When I try: `websocat -H "Authorization: Bearer ...." ws://server/url`, I get the help message. It seems that this tool doesn't handle listening on a web socket with options.

Comment: @NicolasRouquette In this mode options should be specified after the URL to connect. Note that headers for listening and for connecting are separate options.

Answer (score 26):

Try this one from here: [How to hit the WebSocket Endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24704097/how-to-hit-the-websocket-endpoint)

```
$ curl -i -N  \
    -H "Connection: Upgrade"  \
    -H "Upgrade: websocket"  \
    -H "Host: echo.websocket.org"  \
    -H "Origin: http://www.websocket.org"  \
    http://echo.websocket.org
```

Which he has from here: http://www.thenerdary.net/post/24889968081/debugging-websockets-with-curl

To quote the content from this site for the future:

> Those flags say:
>
> 1. Return headers in the output
> 2. Don’t buffer the response
> 3. Set a header that this connection needs to upgrade from HTTP to something else
> 4. Set a header that this connection needs to upgrade to a WebSocket connection
> 5. Set a header to define the host (required by later WebSocket standards)
> 6. Set a header to define the origin of the request (required by later WebSocket standards)

If the websocket is working it should return the following:

```
$ curl -i -N  \
    -H "Connection: Upgrade" \
    -H "Upgrade: websocket" \
    -H "Host: echo.websocket.org" \
    -H "Origin:http://www.websocket.org"  \
    http://echo.websocket.org

HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: Upgrade
WebSocket-Origin: http://www.websocket.org
WebSocket-Location: ws://echo.websocket.org/
Server: Kaazing Gateway
Date: Mon, 11 Jun 2012 16:34:46 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.websocket.org
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-websocket-extensions
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-websocket-version
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-websocket-protocol
```

Comment: ... which I have already mentioned in my question :P No seriousely: I can't get it to work with localhost. I get a HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-type: text/html
on my express.js webserver

Comment: Oh I'm sorry! Maybe you need to handle the update request yourself then? if the server only serves the ws protocol? Because if I understand right, the curl request tries to do a http and update it to a ws protocol - but if the webserver doesn't accept the http incoming calls, nothing can happen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18045352/node-js-how-to-respond-to-an-upgrade-request

Comment: Ok so I thought about what you said. I have'nt heard of this upgrade mechanism before. However, this could of course be the reason why it doesn't work ;) So I have uploaded my node.js app to a online cloud provider now. Therefore I have a http url now. I guess that my express.js framework could internally use the upgrade mechansim, too. How can I add my path and port to the curl command?

Comment: Okay. I was curious what will happen if the connection establishes after the upgrade. Because it is a bidirectional stream, it must be open in the terminal somehow. But how? What will happen? Then I tried this and got this: `curl: (1) Protocol "ws" not supported or disabled in libcurl`
From this one: `curl -i -N -H "Connection: Upgrade" -H "Upgrade: websocket" -H "Host: echo.websocket.org" -H "Origin:http://www.websocket.org" ws://echo.websocket.org/`

Comment: Okay, so to answer your question: I think you can not go that far and do the communication after the upgrade with the linux curl tool. Since you asked about `linux tools`, maybe it could be possible to install something like this https://github.com/progrium/wssh and run then from command line (which can handle the protocol)

Comment: @StefanRein take out the `ws://` from the end of your command

Comment: If you use `curl` you need to use `https://` URL to get it to initiate the TLS connection and then use custom headers to upgrade to websocket connection.

Comment: Note that `socket.io` is not a WebSocket implementation and upgrading connection using standard methods may fail: https://socket.io/docs/v4/#what-socketio-is-not – I think you should use dedicated port if you want to use `socket.io` library and have `socket.io` server listening that port.

Comment: echo.websocket.org service no longer available.

Answer (score 19):

The [vi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266720/vi) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51200659/2397613) provides a very useful tool. `websocat` is so easy to use.

I want to do it only with `bash` builtins. I think it can be useful to others to understand better the protocol.

The [websocket protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) handshake is easy.

To open a `tcp` channel in bash we can use:

```sh
wshost=echo.websocket.org
wsport=80
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/${wshost}/${wsport}
```

Then we can read and write data to that `tcp` connection using file descriptor `&3`.

First let's open a read channel:

```sh
CR=$(echo -en "\r")
while read <&3; do echo "WS MSG:[${REPLY//$CR/}]"; done &
```

We don't really need replace the carriage return bytes `\r`, but the terminal output is weird if we don't.

Each websocket server implementation can require specific details. websocket.org requires `Origin` header and `\r` byte before end line.

Then we can start the connection `upgrade`:

```sh
echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1\r
Host: ${wshost}\r
Connection: Upgrade\r
Upgrade: websocket\r
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $(echo -n "somekey"|base64)\r
Origin: http://www.websocket.org\r
\r" >&3
```

Imediatelly we see the ws upgrade output:

```
$ WS MSG:[HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake]
WS MSG:[Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true]
WS MSG:[Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type]
WS MSG:[Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization]
WS MSG:[Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-websocket-extensions]
WS MSG:[Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-websocket-version]
WS MSG:[Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-websocket-protocol]
WS MSG:[Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.websocket.org]
WS MSG:[Connection: Upgrade]
WS MSG:[Date: Thu, 29 Oct 2020 15:08:01 GMT]
WS MSG:[Sec-WebSocket-Accept: eXT5yQBZ/TOhFBUi6nLY8cfzs1s=]
WS MSG:[Server: Kaazing Gateway]
WS MSG:[Upgrade: websocket]
WS MSG:[]
```

You see the `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` Header ? The server resolve it as described  in [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455). We can calculate it with:

```sh
$ echo -n "$(echo -n "somekey" | base64)258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11" | 
   sha1sum | cut -d " " -f1 | xxd --ps -r  | base64
eXT5yQBZ/TOhFBUi6nLY8cfzs1s=
```

I know... `cut`, `xxd`, `base64` and `sha1sum` are not builtin, but this validation step is just for clarify.

The handshake are done and our tcp connection are now upgraded to a websocket connection.

Now the hard part.

We need to send data. We can learn how to do it in [section 5 of the RFC6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5).

> a client MUST mask all frames that it sends to the server (see Section 5.3 for further details)

and

> The server MUST close the connection upon receiving a frame that is not masked

[Read the RFC Section 5.2 to know how to mask data.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.2)

The RFC even provides a ascii-art for data masking:

```
  0                   1                   2                   3
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
 +-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+-------------------------------+
 |F|R|R|R| opcode|M| Payload len |    Extended payload length    |
 |I|S|S|S|  (4)  |A|     (7)     |             (16/64)           |
 |N|V|V|V|       |S|             |   (if payload len==126/127)   |
 | |1|2|3|       |K|             |                               |
 +-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
 |     Extended payload length continued, if payload len == 127  |
 + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +-------------------------------+
 |                               |Masking-key, if MASK set to 1  |
 +-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
 | Masking-key (continued)       |          Payload Data         |
 +-------------------------------- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
 :                     Payload Data continued ...                :
 + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
 |                     Payload Data continued ...                |
 +---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to write a bash function to mask ws data, but I can not do it now. I'll update this post later.

Comment: Love this dive into the essentials of tcp and websockets, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I've been using wscat, an npm package. https://github.com/websockets/wscat.

Instructions from the package readme at the time of posting:

## Installation

This module needs to be installed globally so use the -g flag when installing:

```
npm install -g wscat
```

## Example

```
$ wscat -c ws://echo.websocket.org
Connected (press CTRL+C to quit)
> hi there
< hi there
> are you a happy parrot?
< are you a happy parrot?
```

Comment: Note that ws://echo.websocket.org service is no longer available

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** `` curl -H 'Upgrade: websocket' -H "Sec-WebSocket-Key: `openssl rand -base64 16`" -H 'Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13' --http1.1 -sSv https://ws.ifelse.io `` (depending on the server you might need to provide `Origin` and/or `Connection: Upgrade`)

First, how does the websocket protocol work in a few words? A client connects to a server, sends a handshake request, receives "101 Switching Protocols" (a handshake response) after which they send [frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Base_Framing_Protocol) back and forth.

The handshake looks along the following lines:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ws.example.com
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: x3JJHMbDL1EzLkh9GBhXDw==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: http://example.com

HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: HSmrc0sMlYUkAGmm5OPpG2HaGWk=
```

[`Upgrade`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Upgrade) makes it switch from HTTP(s) to the websocket protocol.

[`Connection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection) specifies that `Upgrade` is a [hop-by-hop](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9110#field.connection) header (headers that intermediaries should consume, not forward). But my experiments show that it works w/o this header. Or to be more precise, it might be optional if there's a reverse proxy in front of the server (e.g. `nginx`).

[`Sec-WebSocket-Key`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-11.3.1)/[`Sec-WebSocket-Accept`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-11.3.3) is a security measure described [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-11.3.1), [here](https://trac.ietf.org/trac/hybi/wiki/FAQ#WhatSec-WebSocket-KeyandSec-WebSocket-Acceptarefor) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Protocol_handshake).

[`Sec-WebSocket-Version`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-11.3.5) specifies the websocket protocol version. According to RFC 6455 it [should be equal](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#page-18) 13.

[`Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) is needed when the client is a browser and the origin of the requesting page doesn't match the origin of the websocket server URL.

A detailed description of what should constitute a websocket handshake request can be found [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#page-17).

That's how it goes with HTTP/1.1. HTTP/2 is a [different story](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8441).

Knowing this to establish a websocket connection with `curl`:

```
$ curl -H 'Upgrade: websocket' \
       -H "Sec-WebSocket-Key: `openssl rand -base64 16`" \
       -H 'Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13' \
       --http1.1 \
       -sSv \
       https://ws.ifelse.io
...
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: ws.ifelse.io
> Upgrade: websocket
> Sec-WebSocket-Key: e2dujvcbYbN747lapeH+WA==
> Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
...
< HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
< Connection: upgrade
< upgrade: websocket
< sec-websocket-accept: 6wmMGMtN00aWw3loYd6P36EHKMI=
```

The other options are [`wscat`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wscat), [`websocat`](https://github.com/vi/websocat).