# How to read a websocket response with cURL

Tags: curl, websocket

Writing a bash script to connect to [GDAX's Websocket Feed](https://docs.gdax.com/#websocket-feed) at wss://ws-feed.gdax.com but curl doesn't seem to support this as I get

```
curl "wss://ws-feed.gdax.com"
curl: (1) Protocol "wss" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

Comment: You need to compile/install curl with WebSocket support.

Comment: https://curl.se/docs/websocket.html

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Well, you can try to mimic the required headers to get some response using curl:

- https://gist.github.com/htp/fbce19069187ec1cc486b594104f01d0 or
- [Linux Bash: How to open a websocket connection as client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40907888/linux-bash-how-to-open-a-websocket-connection-as-client)

Also, there are other ways to communicate with a WebSocket server, e.g.

- https://github.com/websockets/wscat
- https://github.com/bwasti/webpipe
- https://github.com/progrium/wssh

Answer (score 106):

Assuming you have `node` installed, I would give [`wscat`](https://github.com/websockets/wscat) a shot; it is *simple*, *intuitive*, and *powerful*. Otherwise, @Pavel's answer has an abundance of venerable websocket client alternatives.

```bash
# install
npm install -g wscat

# use
wscat -c "wss://ws-feed.gdax.com"
```

Comment: I think you mean ws not wss as the protocol?

Comment: @Rambatino - The WebSocket protocol [specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455) defines both `ws` (WebSocket) and `wss` (WebSocket Secure).

Comment: aha neat! Thanks for the info :)

Comment: On Ubuntu Bionic it only worked via `sudo apt install node-ws`

Comment: not working with linux pipes

Comment: In Debian-based distros, you can `sudo apt install node-ws`.

Answer (score 27):

I'd like to add my own tool for this: [websocat](https://github.com/vi/websocat).

Example session with the service in question:

```
$ rlwrap websocat wss://ws-feed.gdax.com

# Now enter this line (without the #) for the required JSON request:
# {"type":"subscribe","channels": [{ "name": "heartbeat", "product_ids": ["BTC-USD"] }]}

{"type":"subscriptions","channels":[{"name":"heartbeat","product_ids":["BTC-USD"]}]}
{"type":"heartbeat","last_trade_id":46274575,"product_id":"BTC-USD","sequence":6312079752,"time":"2018-07-12T22:32:42.655000Z"}
{"type":"heartbeat","last_trade_id":46274575,"product_id":"BTC-USD","sequence":6312079800,"time":"2018-07-12T22:32:43.656000Z"}
{"type":"heartbeat","last_trade_id":46274575,"product_id":"BTC-USD","sequence":6312079834,"time":"2018-07-12T22:32:44.656000Z"}
{"type":"heartbeat","last_trade_id":46274575,"product_id":"BTC-USD","sequence":6312079945,"time":"2018-07-12T22:32:45.656000Z"}
{"type":"heartbeat","last_trade_id":46274575,"product_id":"BTC-USD","sequence":6312079990,"time":"2018-07-12T22:32:46.657000Z"}
{"type":"heartbeat","last_trade_id":46274575,"product_id":"BTC-USD","sequence":6312080042,"time":"2018-07-12T22:32:47.657000Z"}
{"type":"heartbeat","last_trade_id":46274576,"product_id":"BTC-USD","sequence":6312080169,"time":"2018-07-12T22:32:48.657000Z"}

# To stop the feed, type this line: 
{"type":"unsubscribe","channels": [{ "name": "heartbeat", "product_ids": ["BTC-USD"] }]}
{"type":"subscriptions","channels":[]}
```

Besides a websocket client, websocat supports WebSocket server and other modes and is aimed to integrate websockets into "UNIX" world in general.

Comment: You forgot to mention that you need to enter the correct JSON request, so I added it.

Comment: `websocat` got me running instantly, even on MacOS! `brew install websocat` then just give the socket server address on the command line and you have a conversation! Awesome!

Answer (score 12):

`ws` start connection by `http` protocol, you have to change `ws` to `http` and some extra headers like this:

```bash
curl --include \
     --no-buffer \
     --header "Connection: Upgrade" \
     --header "Upgrade: websocket" \
     --header "Host: example.com:80" \
     --header "Origin: http://example.com:80" \
     --header "Sec-WebSocket-Key: SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ==" \
     --header "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" \
     "https://ws-feed.gdax.com"
```

https://gist.github.com/htp/fbce19069187ec1cc486b594104f01d0

Comment: how to know the command run success? No error output?@igonejack

Comment: @Dolphin if there are any data received, it shows up

Answer (score 7):

Considering there are `curl` answers here, although with `curl` you can establish a connection but can't send frames, I'll add mine.

The thing with `curl` answers I saw is that they give you some command, but don't explain it. That's the gap I'd like to fill in.

How does the websocket protocol work in a few words? A client connects to a server, sends a handshake request, receives "101 Switching Protocols" (a handshake response) after which they send [frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Base_Framing_Protocol) back and forth.

The handshake looks along the following lines:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ws.example.com
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: x3JJHMbDL1EzLkh9GBhXDw==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: http://example.com

HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: HSmrc0sMlYUkAGmm5OPpG2HaGWk=
```

[`Upgrade`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Upgrade) makes it switch from HTTP(s) to the websocket protocol.

[`Connection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection) specifies that `Upgrade` is a [hop-by-hop](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9110#field.connection) header (headers that intermediaries should consume, not forward). But my experiments show that it works w/o this header. Or to be more precise, it might be optional if there's a reverse proxy in front of the server (e.g. `nginx`).

[`Sec-WebSocket-Key`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-11.3.1)/[`Sec-WebSocket-Accept`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-11.3.3) is a security measure described [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-11.3.1), [here](https://trac.ietf.org/trac/hybi/wiki/FAQ#WhatSec-WebSocket-KeyandSec-WebSocket-Acceptarefor) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Protocol_handshake).

[`Sec-WebSocket-Version`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-11.3.5) specifies the websocket protocol version. According to RFC 6455 it [should be equal](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#page-18) 13.

[`Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) is needed when the client is a browser and the origin of the requesting page doesn't match the origin of the websocket server URL.

A detailed description of what should constitute a websocket handshake request can be found [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#page-17).

That's how it goes with HTTP/1.1. HTTP/2 is a [different story](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8441).

Knowing this to establish a websocket connection with `curl`:

```bash
$ curl -H 'Upgrade: websocket' \
       -H "Sec-WebSocket-Key: `openssl rand -base64 16`" \
       -H 'Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13' \
       --http1.1 \
       -sSv \
       https://ws.ifelse.io
...
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: ws.ifelse.io
> Upgrade: websocket
> Sec-WebSocket-Key: e2dujvcbYbN747lapeH+WA==
> Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
...
< HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
< Connection: upgrade
< upgrade: websocket
< sec-websocket-accept: 6wmMGMtN00aWw3loYd6P36EHKMI=
```

The other options are [wscat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wscat), [websocat](https://github.com/vi/websocat).

Answer (score 4):

Update in the middle of year 2023 :

curl 8 now support websocket protocole but you have to build it with websocket support:

get the sources :

```
git clone https://github.com/curl/curl.git
cd curl
```

after you have to configure the source with websocket support :

```
./configure --with-openssl --enable-ldaps --enable-ldap --disable-dependency-tracking --disable-symbol-hiding --enable-versioned-symbols --enable-threaded-resolver --with-lber-lib=lber --with-gssapi=/usr --with-nghttp2  --includedir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --with-zsh-functions-dir=/usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions --without-libssh --with-libssh2 --enable-websockets
```

and to build it :

```
make
sudo make install
```

And now curl support "ws://" and "wss://" url type and websocket :

```
/usr/src/curl/src/curl -v -i -N -H "X-Fbx-App-Auth: $_SESSION_TOKEN" -H "Connection: Upgrade" -H "Upgrade: websocket" -H "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" -H "Sec-WebSocket-Key: SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ==" -H "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat, superchat" -H "Host: fbx.fbx.lan" -H "Origin: fbx.fbx.lan" "wss://fbx.fbx.lan/api/latest/vm/10/console/" ; stty sane cooked    
* processing: wss://fbx.fbx.lan/api/latest/vm/10/console/
*   Trying 192.168.100.254:443...
* Connected to fbx.fbx.lan (192.168.100.254) port 443
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=FR; ST=PARIS; O=14RV; OU=14RV-NET; CN=*.fbx.lan; emailAddress=nba@fbx.lan
*  start date: Dec 19 08:20:33 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Dec 18 08:20:33 2024 GMT
*  issuer: C=FR; ST=PARIS; O=14RV; OU=14RV-NET; CN=14rv.lan; emailAddress=nba@14rv.lan
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /api/latest/vm/10/console/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: fbx.fbx.lan
> User-Agent: curl/8.2.1-DEV
> Accept: */*
> Connection: Upgrade
> Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
> Sec-WebSocket-Key: Suj7OjwArmF2euYbI5wkkQ==
> X-Fbx-App-Auth: 81q7WBs/I6da+J+78wpkJHLby0Nn9uSk1DrMUZ74TxpIqFBrX6SZCNTCTQULJu5S
> Connection: Upgrade
> Upgrade: websocket
> Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
> Sec-WebSocket-Key: SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ==
> Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat, superchat
> Origin: fbx.fbx.lan
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
< HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
< Server: nginx
< Date: Wed, 26 Jul 2023 09:24:16 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Connection: upgrade
< Upgrade: websocket
< Sec-WebSocket-Accept: rPOYYXjztdK3tPXUEi8jMi0pL60=
< Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: binary
* Received 101, switch to WebSocket; mask 9adae327
<
```

But for the moment, without using libcurl, I didn't succeed in having an interactive session over the websocket like I can have with 'Vitaly Shukela' tools `websocat`

It seems to be normal as the developpment of curl websocket support is quite recent, and at the time I'm writing (2023-07-26), here is what the WEBSOCKET.md file contents :

> ### Command line tool WebSocket
>
> The plan is to make curl do WebSocket similar to telnet/nc.
>
> #### That part of the work has not been started
>
> Ideas:
>
> - Read stdin and send off as messages. Consider newline as end of fragment.    (default to text? offer option to set binary)
> - Respond to PINGs automatically
> - Issue PINGs at some default interval (option to switch off/change interval?)
> - Allow `-d` to specify (initial) data to send (should the format allow for    multiple separate frames?)
> - Exit after N messages received, where N can be zero.
>
> ### Future work
>
> - Verify the Sec-WebSocket-Accept response. It requires a sha-1 function.
> - Verify Sec-WebSocket-Extensions and Sec-WebSocket-Protocol in the response
> - Make WebSocket work with hyper
> - Consider a `curl_ws_poll()`
> - Make sure WebSocket code paths are fuzzed
> - Add client-side PING interval
> - Provide option to disable PING-PONG automation
> - Support compression (`CURLWS_COMPRESS`)

As you can read, this part of the job had not been started but is in project at https://curl.se

So, for the moment, you can use websocket protocole with libcurl but we have to wait for the `curl` command line tool act like `websocat` tool

But you can now use `curl` to test a websocket server like echo.websocket.events

Comment: I had `./configure: No such file or directory`, as there is no `configure` file in the source code. However, in [the releases](https://github.com/curl/curl/releases) there is this file.

Answer (score 3):

You can connect to your server using **Telnet** also

```
telnet 120.22.37.128 6870
```

Once you connect you can send request in **Json** format

```json
{"requestType":"hi"}
```

Here **6870** is port port and to open port you need to run

```
sudo ufw allow 6870
```

And to check pm2 logs you required to  use below command

```
pm2 logs 0
```

Hope this hepls.

Comment: From what I can see you [can't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Base_Framing_Protocol) just send JSON as is. The data should be preceded by a header.