# Opening a socket to see output with bash

Tags: bash, websocket, output

Is it possible to open a socket on a given `URL` and get its output printed, something similar to `curl` but for `TCP` using `bash`?

Currently I am using a `Google Chrome` browser extension -> `Simple Websocket Client` but i would like to make my own scripts and direct the output in my preferred files etc..

Can it be done ?

**PS:** so far I have also used `telnet` but I need to pass a `path` too `host:port:path`.

Comment: Errr... `curl`? I feel like `curl` is the answer. Why it is not working for you?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860689/how-to-read-websocket-response-in-bash) question help you?

Comment: Yes it does thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you version of `bash` supports networking

```
#!/bin/bash
set -u
host="$1"
port="$2"
path="$3"
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/$host/$port
printf '%s\r\n' "$path" >&3
cat <&3
```

if you are hitting a HTTP server the probably you have to pass the `GET` requests as `path`, something like

```
script example.com 80 $'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nConnection: close\r\n'
```